# Animation correction

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have GPS coordinates, which are coming from cars. I'm trying to display their movement using mapbox. It works mostly fine, but because coordinates are imprecise, sometimes markers displayed inside houses, rivers, etc.

Is there a way to specify that the animation should follow the closest road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's exactly what the [Map Matching API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#map-matching) does.